# Maven 2.x Jfrog issues when migrating oracle JDK 1.7 to Azul open JDK 1.8

Tags: maven-2, jfrog-cli, jfrog-mission-control

Migrating our project from oracle Jre 1.7 to Azul open Jre1.8 using maven 2.2.1. During the compilation we are hitting the Jfrog issues with jade-Multijar.

“jade-multijar-plugin” version 1.3.2 from Maven 2.x. And later maven 3.x there is no jade-multijar-plugin jars. Want to fix this Jfrog issue.

Error  Message :
message : Cannot construct org.jfrog.maven.plugins.common.deploy.Deployment as it does not have a no-args constructor
cause-exception : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ObjectAccessException
cause-message : Cannot construct org.jfrog.maven.plugins.common.deploy.Deployment as it does not have a no-args constructor

```
<groupId>org.jfrog.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>jade-multijar-plugin</artifactId>
```

maven 2.x with oracle jre 1.7 codes worked fine. When we migrate open JDK azul jre 1.8 the issue persist.

Comment: please provide full stacktrace error. At one point, it should be thrown by one of the JDK core class

Comment: @ Wisthler I am unable to post the entire trace. Few are below.

Comment: Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ObjectAccessException: Cannot construct org.jfrog.maven.plugins.common.deploy.Deployment as it does not have a no-args constructor
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.newInstance(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:71)
 at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.instantiateNewInstance(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:424)
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:229)